# javascript get external table row on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button:

```
<button id="external-list-row">Test</button>
```

in which I would like to change with a row from an external table on click. The external table is structured like this;

```
<table id="table_id">

<thead> 
<tr> 
    <th>X</th> 
    <th>Y</th> 
</tr> 
</thead> 

<tbody>
<tr> 
    <td> 
      <p>Row 1</p>
    </td> 
</tr>
<tr> 
    <td> 
      <p>Row 2</p>
    </td> 
</tr>
<tr> 
    <td> 
      <p>Row 3</p>
    </td> 
</tr>
</tbody> 

</table>
```

So my question is this; how can I replace "Test" in the button with the content of Row 1 with javascript?

As for the javascript, I'm not sure how I can get the content from row 1, and replace the button with it.

```
<script>
    var rows = document.getElementById('table_id').getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for (var i=0; i<rows.length; i++) {
        $('#external-list-row').onclick = function() {
        }};
</script>
```

---

**Post comments:**

I can access table data from other tables within the same html file, but I still don't know how to access data from tables in other html files. For example, if I try to access a videos liquid file from another liquid file, like photos, nothing happens when I press the button.

Fiddle of current code. It can replace the content of a list with the content of another, but the lists need to be on the same html file.
https://jsfiddle.net/hgnymydL/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is jquery code of do this

```js
    $('#table_id tr td').on('click', function(){
      $('#external-list-row').html($(this).html());
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="external-list-row">Test</button>


<table id="table_id">

<thead> 
<tr> 
    <th>X</th> 
    <th>Y</th> 
</tr> 
</thead> 

<tbody>
<tr> 
    <td> 
      <p>Row 1</p>
    </td> 
</tr>
<tr> 
    <td> 
      <p>Row 2</p>
    </td> 
</tr>
<tr> 
    <td> 
      <p>Row 3</p>
    </td> 
</tr>
</tbody> 

</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for the working answer, Bhavin Solanki. I thought about making it the other way around by having Row 1 replace the "Test" button, but I believe this can be helpful for other coding situations. Would it be possible to use images with your code?

Comment: Hi again, @Bhavin, I accepted your answer, because it includes images and links as well. However, I still don't know how to access table data from a different html file. Would you happen to know how I could do that as well? So far, it works when the tables are on the same html file, but I would like to access tables in other html files too.

Comment: You need to post different question with updated code and fiddle

Comment: Ok, but I do have external table row in the original question. However, I have made a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hgnymydL/ It can give an idea of what I want to do.

Comment: This answer is also adding the "<p>" tags to the textContent of the button, instead of just the textContent of the cell.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the first thing you should understand, is that a `table` element has a `rows` property, so getting the first row is trivial.

```
var table = document.getElementById("table_id");
var firstRow = table.rows[0];
```

From there, you can use `textContent` to get the text content of the row. I believe that's what you were looking for.

You can also select the first row of a table with a CSS selector like so:

```
var firstRow = document.querySelector("#table_id tbody tr");
```

Comment: Hello, @Josh. Thank you, it worked with:
`$('#external-list-row').on('click', function() {
    var table = document.getElementById("table_id");
    var FirstRow = table.rows[1].textContent;
    document.getElementById("external-list-row").innerHTML = FirstRow;
});`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#external-list-row').on('click', function() {
    $(this).text($('#table_id tbody tr:first').text());
});
```

Comment: Thanks, @jmar777, it works great, but since I have received several working answers, I will need some time to decide the "best" one.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to replace the visible text "Test" in the button with the content of the cell clicked:

```
var tbl = document.getElementById('table_id');
var btn = document.getElementById('external-list-row');

tbl.onclick = function(ev){
    var trgt = ev.target;

    if(trgt.tagName === 'P' ||trgt.tagName === 'TD'){
        btn.textContent = trgt.textContent;
    }
};
```

Only one event handler is attached in this scenario.

Via event delegation we determine if it was a TD or P element that was clicked. If the rows are modified the function will still work.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution, Mychal Hackman, but when I test the code, nothing seems to happen with the "Test" button. Perhaps something is missing?

Comment: Ah, you must be using Firefox. I didn't realise Firefox doesn't support innerText, instead it supports the standard textContent. My bad, the answer has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace the button text with contents of the **First Row ONLY** then:

```
$('#external-list-row').html($('tr:first-child').html);
```

Of course you could wrap this in any event, so for example, on clicking the button:

```
$('#external-list-row').on('click', function() {
    $(this).html($('tr:first-child').text());
});
```

BUT, based on the code you have given, I'm assuming you want to change the text after each click in which case you could do this:

```
var clickNumber = -1;

$('#external-list-row').on('click', function(event) {
    clickNumber = clickNumber + 1;
    //console.log('\n\nclickNUmber' + clickNumber);

    $('tbody tr').each(function(index, el) {
        //console.log('index: ' + index);
        var block = $(el).find('td p');
        if(index == clickNumber) {
            //console.log('entered if')
            //console.log(block.text());
            //console.log('----clickNUmber' + clickNumber);
            //console.log('index: ' + index);
            //console.log(el);
            $('#external-list-row').html(block.text());
        }
    });
});
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zmb2b37t/

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you, Sukrit Chhabra, it does work, but do you know how I could specify a specific table id, and can java or jquery accommodate img too?

Comment: Hi Erlend, you instead of `$('tbody tr')` you can write `$('#idOfTable tbody tr')` for table ID.

You can accomodate `img` too but instead of `block.text()` you would do 
```
var block = $(el).find('td img');

$('#external-list-row').html(block.attr('src'));

```